# Is it possible to scroll list view and an image simultaneously?

Tags: java, android, build.xml

Is there anyone who can help me with this can I get a image on an activity and on the same activity..a list view and when we scroll the list view ...the image on top of the listview also get scrolled up...I know that collapsing toolbar is a soln but I don't want to use collapsing toolbar???
Can anyone help me with this ??

Comment: Why don't you want to use CollapsingToolbar? That is exactly what CollpasingToolbr is for

Answer (score 1):

I don't know with `ListView` but you can use `RecyclerView`

example

```
recyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {

        int y = 0;
        @Override
        public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
            super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);
            y += dy;
            if (y < 0) {
                y = 0;
            }

            int imageHeight = yourImageView.getHeight();

            final float ratio = (float) Math.min(Math.max(y, 0), imageHeight) / imageHeight;

            yourImageView.setTranslationY(ratio * -yourImageView.getHeight());
        }
    });
```

if you want to use with `ListView` then try to get scrollY of `ListView` then use the above code

Note that `int dy` is The amount of vertical scroll.

Comment: I will try to do